# Big Query Select rows in between two values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to select rows in between two values using big query.

Here the table is:

```
ID     Group     values
1       A         10I
1       B         20I
1       C         30I
1       D         40I
1       E         50I
1       F         60I
1       G         70I
1       H         80I
1       I         90I
```

Here I need to select rows from Group C to G.

The code i'm using is:

```
select * from data
where Group >= 'C' and Group <='G'
```

The above code gave no results.

Also i tried:

```
select * from data
where Group between 'C' and 'G'
```

This also returned no results.

Someone please provide a solution.

Comment: Unclear how robust of a solution you need.  Does something like `SELECT * FROM data WHERE Group in ('C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G')` meet your need?

Answer (score 0):

This is because "Group" is a reserved word (the GROUP BY): BQ expects you to group something and didn't understand that here it is the name of a column. To make BQ understand just as backslashes:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE `Group` BETWEEN "C" AND "G"
```